# php, issue with gd library

Tags: php, image, gd

I'm using lamp on linux, and on a phpinfo I can see that gd is enable.
this code is working:

```
<?php
header ("Content-type: image/png");
$image = imagecreatefrompng("photo.png");
imagepng($image);
?>
```

but when I'm trying

```
<?php
$image = imagecreatefrompng("photo.png");
imagepng($image, "test.png");
?>
```

I have this error message:

Warning: imagepng(test.png): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /opt/lampp/htdocs/gd/mypage.php on line 3

any idea why??

Comment: Because your script/the user the script runs as doesn't have write permissions in that directory. As the error says.

Comment: You may want to try changing the location you are writing to from "test.png" to an absolute path to a directory you know is writable (like "/tmp/test.png").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to check chmod on folder. Or set them chmod 777, after do what you want to do with images. Also read [this manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php)

Answer (score 0):

You dont have permissions to write in the current folder.
Try creating a folder and then giving it permissions from the terminal:

```
# mkdir /path to project/uploads
# su -c "chmod 777 /path to project/uploads"
```

And then modify your script:

```
imagepng($image, "uploads/test.png");
```